# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor$Logger

Tags: android

I have such dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0' 
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'   
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.9.0' 
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile "net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport:1.5.1"
}
```

and building of my project is always finishing with the following error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.icard.rest, PID: 13758
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor$Logger at
>   okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:116)
>   at com.comp.model.App.onCreate(App.java:30) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4464)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I suppose that some of these libraries are incompatible. But how to fix this?

Comment: Are you compiling using Proguard?

Comment: same problem for `3.8.0` ?

Comment: @WoogieNoogie, yes, I enable Proguard by `minifyEnabled true`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, and yes, with 3.8.0 the same error occurs

Comment: Oh, I fixed it just now :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I used `multiDexEnabled true`, but I haven't included

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
```

After I included this dependency and change my code from

```
App extends Application
```

to

```
App extends MultiDexApplication
```

the problem disappeared.